# How to get CGRect of UIImageView after CGAffineTransformRotate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cgrect

In my game I'm rotating UIImageview to 30-degrees and I need to get transformed CGRect of rotated UIImageview, please some one help me with sample code.

```
UIImageView *mainImgB = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, hight)];
[mainImgB setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
mainImgB.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
mainImgB.center = CGPointMake(View.frame.size.width/2, View.frame.size.height/2);
mainImgB.transform =  CGAffineTransformRotate(mainImgB.transform,30 * M_PI/180);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `CGRectApplyAffineTransform` :

```
 CGRect newRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(yourViewOnWhichTransformGetsApplied.frame, yourTransformHere);
```

Comment: You mean: CGRect newRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(mainImgB.frame, mainImgB.transform);, but still i'm not getting correct CGRect

Comment: After transform still my CGRect way off, please some one share working code sample.